# Gorm Foreign Keys

Tags: go, foreign-keys, go-gorm

Anyone knows why this code is not working and how to solve it?

```
type Model struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time `sql:"index"`
}

func (model *Model) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    model.ID = uuid.New()
    return
}

type User struct {
    Model
    Name                string
    Email               string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Description         string
    AccountCredentials  AccountCredentials  `gorm:"foreignKey:Email,constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,onDelete:CASCADE"`
    AccountVerification AccountVerification `gorm:"foreignKey:Email,constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,onDelete:CASCADE"`
}

type AccountCredentials struct {
    Email    string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Password string
}

type AccountVerification struct {
    Email               string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    VerificationCode    string
    VerificationCodeTTL int64
    IsVerified          bool
    CreatedAt           time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime:true"`
}
```

When I'm automigrating the DB:

```
    db.AutoMigrate(&model.AccountCredentials{}, &model.AccountVerification{}, &model.User{})
```

I'm receiving the following errors:

invalid field found for struct pkg/model.User's field AccountCredentials: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typo is in using `,` instead of `;`, also use the `references`:

```
type Model struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time `sql:"index"`
}

func (model *Model) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    model.ID = uuid.New()
    return
}

type User struct {
    Model
    Name                string
    Email               string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Description         string
    AccountCredentials  AccountCredentials  `gorm:"foreignKey:Email;references:Email;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    AccountVerification AccountVerification `gorm:"foreignKey:Email;references:Email;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE"`
}

type AccountCredentials struct {
    Email    string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Password string
}

type AccountVerification struct {
    Email               string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    VerificationCode    string
    VerificationCodeTTL int64
    IsVerified          bool
    CreatedAt           time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime:true"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it's working as expected.